# Constraint Error running pg_partman.run_maintenance()

Tags: postgresql, constraints, pg-partman

I have a partitioned table that have a partition named tablename_default and also a pool of partitions created the first time. Now tablename_default has records that go beyond the monthly partition parameter and when i run pg_partman.run_maintenance() the upcoming error its

```
SQL Error [P0001]: ERROR: updated partition constraint for default partition would be violated by some row
CONTEXT: SQL statement "ALTER TABLE raw.bupa_trace_resultados ATTACH PARTITION raw.bupa_trace_resultados_p2023_11 FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-11-01 00:00:00-03') TO ('2023-12-01 00:00:00-03')"
PL/pgSQL function create_partition_time(text,timestamp with time zone[],boolean,boolean) line 222 at EXECUTE
PL/pgSQL function partman.run_maintenance(text,boolean,boolean,boolean) line 280 at assignment
DETAIL: 
HINT: 
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function create_partition_time(text,timestamp with time zone[],boolean,boolean) line 442 at RAISE
PL/pgSQL function partman.run_maintenance(text,boolean,boolean,boolean) line 280 at assignment
DETAIL: 
HINT: 
  Where: PL/pgSQL function partman.run_maintenance(text,boolean,boolean,boolean) line 398 at RAISE
```

I think it may be because the default_table has records that are going to fall into the partitions that are about to be created, so the constraint is triggered.

Can you please help me?

I tried running partman.run_maintenance() with the verbosity parameters to get more details, but I only referred to the create_partition_time function where I couldn't get any more answers.

What I am looking for is that as the additional partitions are created when running run_maintenance, the records that exist in the default_table are emptied in the new partitions created

Comment: I also see the same error. After a month all the data start going into the default partition.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am looking for is that as the additional partitions are created when running run_maintenance, the records that exist in the default_table are emptied in the new partitions created.

As far as I understand that is not possible. I am no expert but if you have data in your default partition you can run:

```
postgres=# CALL partman.partition_data_proc('raw.bupa_trace_resultados');
```

to move it out and to the partitioned tables. I think you will have to make sure you are calling `partman.run_maintenance` before data gets inserted into the default partition.